# Laravel: set constant/variable based on domain name

Tags: php, laravel, domain-name

I'm building an application that has multiple domain names linked to it and different front-end views/websites based on and linked to those domain names.

Now I would like to set some variables based on the domain name and make them usable in my controllers and application logic.

for example, all views for the different front-ends are stored in different folders based on the domain name (ziv, dbg, dbe). So let's say, if a user reaches the application via example.com a variable must be set so that the views loaded will be from the folder "exm". It would look like this:

```
View::make('frontend.' . $folderVariable . '.home')->with('info', $info);
```

My question is: where should I place such code?

Should it be in the bootstrap file, or in a base controller that all other controllers will inherit? I do need the information on the domain name throughout the whole application, so it needs to be loaded up front.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i had place it into the base controller in my project.. but not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: In Laravel 4.2 you can do that in `App:before()` located at `/app/filters.php`. Use `View::share()` to have it available throughout the views or `Config::set()` to have it available everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a Service class to handle the current domain and return an appropriate string to use with the `View::make()` method.

Either that or extend the View class `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\View` to override the `View::make()` or to create another method that inserts the relevant string automatically. Also optionally utilising a service provider.

Example of the service class - it doesn't need a service provider (depends on the implementation)

```
class DomainResolver
{
    private $subdomains;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Contains sub domain mappings
        $this->subdomains = array(
            'accounts' => 'ziv',
            'billing' => 'exm'
            //Etc etc
        );
    }

    public function getView($view)
    {
        // Should return the current domain/subdomain
        // Replace if I'm wrong (untested)
        $subdomain = \Route::getCurrentRoute->domain();

        if(isset($this->subdomains[$subdomain]))
        {
            return View::make($this->subdomains[$subdomain].'.'$view);
        }
        throw new \Exception('Invalid domain');
    }
}
```

You would then insert this class where you needed to have a domain specific function performed. I.e - BaseController, View functionality extensions (you could make `View::domainMake()` that would just call the service class with the value given.

Comment: So in the ServiceProvider boot method I would put some logic that checks the domain and sets some vars? How would I make that accessible in my controllers for example?

Comment: It's a nice solution but it's just for the views. I also want to be able to load different API keys from my config files based on the domain name. Therefore I would like the domain variables to be accessible throughout the application and not just for the views. Do you think that putting this logic in a public function in the base controller and loading that method in the base controllers constructor is better for the functionality I would like? Or isn't this the best solution?

Comment: Extending the controller is an option but what if you need that functionality in a different part of your application? Usage of a service class means you can place that class any where in your application and reuse it whilst also making it easily testable. You could then use that service class in an extendable controller AND in the view extension method. If you haven't used service classes before then look in to it, there are many tutorials available.

Comment: So you would suggest creating a service provider for checking the logic on the domain name and setting the variables in there? How would I acces the variables then?

Comment: Edited the question, the service class (not provider!) would be inserted where needed as a singleton to perform various things such as getting the correct view from the correct folder according to the domain name, it could even have a config file to dictate where to retrieve views for each domain but that's outside of the scope of your question (Google it). If you haven't used service classes before, look it up. You place them pretty much any where. I place them in a folder in the app dir and set up PSR-4 autoloading to make it all purr.

Comment: Ah I get it! You create some sort of a "support class" that can be injected in your controllers or elsewhere in your application which is capable of retrieving the domain and returning information on the domain name (such as the 3 character code). And if needed you can bind this class to the container via a service provider. Thanks very much!

Comment: I wouldn't condemn it to just "Support". I use them extensively to develop. And you are correct. I should have mentioned dependency injection from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a middleware like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class DetectDomainMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example.com')
        {
          define('domain', 'exm');
        }
        elseif($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example-B.com')
        {
          define('domain', 'B');
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and [register this middleware to the kernel.php as global](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#registering-middleware), so it will be executed on each HTTP request.

Now in every file (Controller / View / etc.) you can check on which domain you are

```
<?php

  if(domain == 'exn') {..}
  if(domain == 'B') {..}
```

Your view command could be changed to

```
View::make('frontend.' . domain . '.home')->with('info', $info);
```